# serverSocketChannel.accept() returns null

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking

I am trying to write a simple client server program in Java NIO.

Here is the code:

```java
package org.lb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
    serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    while (true) {
      selector.select();
      Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeySet = selector.selectedKeys();
      for (SelectionKey selectionKey : selectionKeySet) {
        if (selectionKey.isAcceptable()) {
          SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
          if (socketChannel == null) {
            System.out.println("No connection...");
          } else {
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            System.out.println("Connection done!");
          }
        }

        if (selectionKey.isReadable()) {
          System.out.println("isReadable");
          SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();
          socketChannel.close();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see that I call `serverSocketChannel.accept()` only when `selectionKey.isAcceptable()` returns true. So, I assume that `serverSocketChannel.accept()` should always return a valid `SocketChannel` instance, but sometimes it's returning null as well.

I am trying to send request using Postman, but the same case is with browser requests too.

##### Output with Postman single request

```
Connection done!
No connection...
isReadable
Connection done!
No connection...
isReadable
```

I expected that `Connection done!` is printed once, but it's printing twice. Also, why `No connection...` is printed?

##### Output with curl single request

```
Connection done!
isReadable
No connection...
```

Comment: From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#accept()): _"**Returns**:  The socket channel for the new connection, or `null` if this channel is in non-blocking mode and no connection is available to be accepted"_

Comment: What i can see about `isAcceptable` from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#isAcceptable()) is, `isAcceptable` return true if this key's channel is ready to accept a new socket connection. And i am calling `serverSocketChannel.accept()` only when `isAcceptable()` is true. So, it should not return null.

Comment: I hardly ever program NIO, but shouldn't you remove the selection key from the set after you processed it? In other words, given you don't remove it, subsequent calls to `selectedKeys()` continue to return it, even if there currently is nothing waiting.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is correct. The key was still acceptable from last time.

Comment: It was resolved, thanks @MarkRotteveel